# Calling SAP Client from VBA Excel

Tags: c++, vba, abap, excel-interop

Is there a way to call the SAP Client to retrieve some data when using Excel and VBA? And if there is a way to do that, can You tell me how?

Since I heard that I just can't use any database driver to access the HANA database like every other MySQL/SQLite/... database. I have to access them through the SAP Client. The client will take care there are no consitency errors, which I can understand, but why should reading cause consistency problems?? But this is another topic.

Calling a .NET libary through the `CLR Execution Engine 2.4 Library` is possible, even calling native C/C++ functions through P/Ivoke, but calling the SAP client, written in ABAP (as I assume)??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The only answer to this question would be "yes", which is unlikely to be helpful to anyone. Please be more specific in your question.

Answer (score 1):

One idea could be to create a Webservice within the SAP System (assuming we are on an ABAP stack) like SOAP or better OData and call this Webservice inside your Excel/VBA. Doing HTTP requests with VBA seems fairly easy for what i can see right now.

Comment: I would recommend this method too. Interfaces are far better monitored (or at least able to) than direct RFC. An RFC can be directly exposed as a web service by any ABAP developer.

Answer (score 0):

You can call RFC function in Excel VBA. You need GUI installation for usage. Debug operation worst. Example here: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?337408-VB-and-SAP-Integration